# Method not found at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have the following extension in my personal toolbox library:

```
public extension UIViewController {

    public func removeChildViewControllers() {
        for child in self.childViewControllers {
            child.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            child.view.removeFromSuperview()
           child.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
   }

    public func addChildViewController(_ controller: UIViewController, embedViewIn containerView: UIView) {
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.addCustomConstraints(CustomConstrains.FullSizeInSuperview)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

From my current app, I call as follows:

```
private func embedViewController(_ controller: UIViewController) {
    removeChildViewControllers()    
    addChildViewController(controller, embedViewIn: containerView)
}
```

Everything is working as expected.

Now I add one more convenience Method `removeChildViewController`:

```
public extension UIViewController {

    public func removeChildViewControllers() {
        for child in self.childViewControllers {
            child.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            child.view.removeFromSuperview()
           child.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
   }

    public func addChildViewController(_ controller: UIViewController, embedViewIn containerView: UIView) {
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.addCustomConstraints(CustomConstrains.FullSizeInSuperview)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    public func removeChildViewController(_ controller: UIViewController) {
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controller.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

From now on, calling the code which has not been modified crashes at runtime EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
removeChildViewControllers()
```

To sum it up:

Calling `removeChildViewControllers()` crashes on runtime if the (unused) method `removeChildViewController` exists.

Calling `removeChildViewControllers()` does not crash on runtime if the  (unused) method `removeChildViewController` is commented.

Also, calling `removeChildViewControllers()` does not crash on runtime if the  (unused) method `removeChildViewController` is renamed to `removeChildViewControllerr`.

Comment: Have you tried to add Exception breakpoint to catch the exact line where your app crashes?

Comment: I have the "All Execptions" breakpoint, which breaks calling `removeChildViewControllers() `. The extension lifes in my library, so I assume the exeption breakpoint might not stop in the libraries code.

Comment: "so I can not debug in there." Why not? Of course you can debug in a library, what is stopping you?

Comment: What happens if you give `addChildViewController` a different name? I'm wondering if the runtime is getting it confused with the `addChildViewController` that already exists. You could just try `myAddChildViewController`, at least temporarily, to see if it helps things.

Comment: The extension lifes in my library, so I assume the exeption breakpoint might not stop in the libraries code. I also set a manual breakpoint in `removeChildViewControllers`, which is never reached.

Comment: I already tried this. Renaming `addChildViewController` did not change the behaviour, BUT renaming `removeChildViewController` (the new method) fixes it.

Comment: I had a copy & past error in the question, which is fixed now. `removeChildViewController` is the trouble maker, not `addChildViewController`. Sorry.

Comment: Pretty interesting stuff.

Comment: Yes, pretty scary too :-)

Comment: What is a personal toolbox library? I'd love to have a way where all my utility methods / extensions just magically show up in every project I write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127659/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-matt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this is one of those situations where you are banging into a secret namespace conflict. There probably *is* a `removeChildViewController` method hidden in the Objective-C Cocoa world, and you have stumbled over it by duplicating its name. Thus, Objective-C Cocoa chokes at runtime, even though the official API has no problem with it and so there is no trouble getting Swift to compile your code. This sort of thing happens all the time, unfortunately.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you explain more detailed what happens in this case? Why does onother method cause the crash in this case (`removeChildViewControllers`)? Does this render the whole extension unreachable?

Comment: This is really a fail in the documentation: the fact that Swift extension definitions will clobber _just like_ ObjC categories do should be mentioned explicitly in the "Swift with Cocoa/ObjC" book.